# WebStorm Vue Unresolved variable or type

Tags: vue.js, ide, webstorm, vuex

I have upgraded my WebStorm to version 2019.2.1 yesterday.

[image: orm]

After that I have some issues with Vuex methods:

[image]

Methods and computed added locally works fine and are recognized by WebStorm (green arrows)

But getters and actions are not: `Unresolved variable or type...` (blue and red arrows)

This is misleading + I can't use shortcut to jump to method.

How can I make it work?

---

UPDATE

Adding `this.` before like: changing `canBeEdited` to `this.canBeEdited` solves the error but it seems to be a hack (not very comfortable though)

Answer (score 2):

Submitted to developers as [WEB-40929](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40929), please follow it for updates